How to prove the SSS triangle congruence without isosceles triangles or circles?
The SSS triangle congruence is the following theorem from elementary geometry:

If three sides of a triangle are equal to the three sides of another triangle, then the two triangles are congruent.

The proof of which I know is the following:

Let $_\Delta ABC$ and $_\Delta A_1B_1C_1$ be two triangles with $AB=A_1B_1$, $AC=A_1C_1$, and $BC=B_1C_1$.
Assume the contrary that $_\Delta ABC \ncong _\Delta A_1B_1C_1$. Then it implies that $\angle A \neq \angle A_1$, $\angle B \neq \angle B_1$, and $\angle C \neq \angle C_1$, because if even one pair of these angles are equal, then these triangles would be equal by SAS.
By axiom of existence of congruent triangle, there exists a triangle $_\Delta A_1B_2C_2 \cong _\Delta ABC$ such that point $B_2$ lies on ray $A_1B_1$, and point $C_2$ lies on the same half-plane with point $C_1$ in relation to line $A_1B_1$.
By axiom of segment construction, $\begin{cases}B_2 \in \vec{A_1B_1}, \\ A_1B_1 = A_2B_2;\end{cases}\Rightarrow B_1 \equiv B_2$.
Let $M$ be the midpoint of segment $C_1C_2$.
$_\Delta A_1C_1C_2$ and $_\Delta B_1C_1C_2$ are both isosceles triangles with common base $C_1C_2$.
Therefore, their medians $A_1M$ and $B_1M$ are also altitudes, which implies $A_1M \perp C_1C_2$, $B_1M \perp C_1C_2$.
Points $A_1$, $B_1$, and $M$ are not collinear, therefore they can't be coincident.
But only one perpendicular to a line can pass through a point on that line.
Therefore, we came to the contradiction. QED.

I would like to have an elementary proof that does not involve isosceles triangles or circles. I'd like to know a derivation of SSS through axioms, just like SAS and ASA.
I use a set of axioms referred to as 'Pogorelov axioms':
I want to use the following as axioms:
Axiom 1: Each plane has collinear points and noncollinear points. Through two points passes one and only one line.
Axiom 2: Three points on a straight line are such that only one is between two others.
Axiom 3: Each line segment has a positive length. A length of a line segment is equal to the sum of lengths of its parts.
Axiom 4: Any straight line on a plane splits it into two half-planes.
Axiom 5: Each angle has a positive degree measure. A measure of a straight angle is equal to 180 degrees. A degree measure of an angle is equal to the sum of lengths of angles, on which it is split by any ray passing in between its sides.
Axiom 6: There is only one way to construct a line segment of a given length on a given ray from its vertex.
Axiom 7: There is only one way to construct an angle of a given measure less than 180 degrees from a given ray at a given half-plane.
Axiom 8: In a plane, given a line and a point not on it, at most one line parallel to the given line can be drawn through the point.

Till date, I know the fact that if an axiom is sufficient to prove the congruence of two triangles, then the data required to present the axiom can be used to find the area of them. You can infact find the area of a triangle from its sides, by Heron's formula.

@Gwen Heron's formula is fine, though equiareal triangles may be non-congruent. Can you put more details to that approach? It seems like 'equal sides, equal areas mean equal altitudes'.

I actually have used it all my life (of 17 years) like a lemma. Never thought of it very deeply. I'm trying to come up with some details.

How about using trig to find the angles of the triangle to get AAA hence similar, and the side length then imply congruent?

But those properties of isosceles triangles can be proved using only SAS and ASA. Why don't you like them?

@CalvinLin Trig does depend on some preliminary knowledge about right triangles, which doesn't really serve much optimization.

@Intelligentipauca I am just wondering whether the isosceles triangle knowledge is the simpliest way to the SSS, or there are other, more direct ways to prove this basic fact.

Hilbert, in his "Foundations of Geometry", writes: "The theorem relating to the congruence of the base angles A and B of an equilateral triangle ABC follows immediately by the application of axiom IV, 6 [which is equivalent to SAS congruence theorem] to the triangles ABC and BAC. By aid of this theorem, in addition to theorem 14 [stating that all right angles are congruent to one another], we can easily demonstrate the following proposition [which is the SSS congruence theorem]." I don't think we can do better than him.

What axiom system are you using? The default axiom system is Euclid's, which has no "axiom of existence". While Hilbert's system is the most commonly used of complete systems, there are many others, so if you want a proof under your system, you need to tell us which system that is.

@PaulSinclair Done, edited my question.

Axiom 8 appears to be mistated. Any point is always co-planar with any line (i.e., there is always a plane that contains both). But there is only one line parallel to the given line and passing through the point. It is that parallel line which will be co-planar to the given line.

@PaulSinclair This is my mistake during the translation. I'll reformat it as a Playfair axiom.

I would still wonder how, in your axiom system, the concept of congruence is defined.

I don't see among your axioms anything equivalent to SAS congruence: how do you prove it?
